# Uppercase headings with uppercase numbers

Tags: sectioning, fontspec, titlesec, opentype

I'm trying to get uppercase section titles with uppercase numbers,
but for some reason `\addfontfeature` can't be used inside `\titleformat`.
Why is that and how could I get this to work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{ebgaramond}

\titleformat{\section}{\filcenter\uppercase}
  {\addfontfeature{Numbers=Lining}\thesection. }{0pt}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Uppercase numbers}
Uppercase letters should be accompanied by uppercase numbers.
\end{document}
```

>

```
ERROR: LaTeX error: "kernel/key-unknown"

--- TeX said ---
! 
! The key 'fontspec/NUMBERS' is unknown and is being ignored.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.10 \section{Uppercase numbers}

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| The module 'fontspec' does not have a key called 'fontspec/NUMBERS'.
| Check that you have spelled the key name correctly.
|...............................................
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to define a new font family:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{EB Garamond}[Numbers=Lining]

\titleformat{\section}
  {\filcenter\titlefont}
  {\thesection. }
  {0pt}
  {\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}
\section{Uppercase numbers}
Uppercase letters should be accompanied by uppercase numbers.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the right position of `\MakeUppercase` (not `\uppercase`) and of the font declaration.